# Does the pipe character mean more than bitwise OR in Java?

Tags: java, android, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I see constructs similar to the following a lot (in android since I do mostly android in Java)

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsWM
...
paramsWM.gravity = Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT;
```

So is it simply taking the bitwise OR of the two values or is there more to this than meets the eye? If it's just the bitwise OR, then in the above I would end up with

```
//think math, not java for syntax below
paramsWM.gravity = Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT = 48|3=51;
```

Again, if it's just bitwise, this shortcut is only permissible when I know the recipient (i.e. `paramsWM.gravity`) can handle the addition: right? Furthermore, could I equally have written

```
//this is java again
final WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsWM
...
paramsWM.gravity = Gravity.TOP + Gravity.LEFT;
```

Comment: `|` is also enabled for boolean expressions. In such cases it works like `||` but without short-cutting.

Answer (score 0):

The pipe character simply takes the bitwise OR, nothing more, nothing less.

Here's a nice example for all bitwise operators:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_bitwise_operators_examples.htm

EDIT: As stated by user PM 77-1 in the comments, it's also used in bool expressions if you don't want to short-circuit